# How to pass data generated by a Databricks notebook to a Python step?

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, fastparquet

I am building an Azure Data Factory v2, which comprises

- A Databricks step to query large tables from Azure Blob storage and generate a tabular result `intermediate_table`;
- A Python step (which does several things and would be cumbersome to put in a single notebook) to read the `processed_table` and generate the final output.

And looks like this

[image]

The notebook generates a `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` which I tried to save into parquet format with attempts like

```
processed_table.write.format("parquet").saveAsTable("intermediate_table", mode='overwrite')
```

or

```
processed_table.write.parquet("intermediate_table", mode='overwrite')
```

Now, I would like the Python step to re-read the intermediate result, ideally with a `postprocess.py` file with a syntax like

```
import pandas as pd
intermediate = pd.read_parquet("intermediate_table")
```

after having installed `fastparquet` inside my Databricks cluster.
This is (not surprisingly...) failing with errors like

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   './my_processed_table'

I assume the file is not found because the Python file is not accessing the data in the right context/path.

How should I amend the code above, and what would be the best/canonical ways to pass data across such steps in a pipeline? (any other advice on common/best practices to do this are welcome)

Comment: Would saving the file to DBFS help with this issue?

Comment: Anything goes really, I am new to data factories and Databricks so I am not sure what best practices are here! If I save to dbfs (which I think is what `write.parquet` does) how should I load the file in the Python step though? `pd.read_parquet("dbfs:/my_processed_table")` also fails...

Comment: The saveAsTable may not work with DBFS. I'd have to mess with it myself to see if that works, though. This is all  mainly just a thought :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to run the pipeline successfully is to have in the Databricks notebook a cell like

```
%python

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
import pandas as pd
processed_table.toPandas().to_parquet("/dbfs/intermediate", engine="fastparquet", compression = None)
```

and then have in `preprocess.py`

```
import pandas as pd
intermediate = pd.read_parquet("/dbfs/intermediate")
```

not sure if that's good practice (it works though).